# Google Script Editor in iOS 14.4

Tags: google-apps-script, ipad, ide, mobile-safari

I am accessing the script editor on an iPad - iOS 14.4 via Safari. The old editor populates without on starting script and the menu and option to go to the new editor do not function.  Everything works fine in Chrome on my Mac, problem only exists on the iPad in Safari.

Any suggestions to use the editor in this situation?

[image]

Comment: Try installing Chrome on your IPad and see if you can get the Apps Script IDE (the editor) to open from there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I might suggest you try the "Request Desktop site" option, which you can get to by pressing the top left (two small aA) on the Safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome on my iPad didn't run for me. I had to use an Android device to get the old editor to work properly, so you could try that. Then on that device, switch to the new editor.